# tkinter widget implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I am kind of new to classes and tkinter in general. This is my code, I have been trying to a simple interface in which I can choose the starting date and end date in order to identify an interval.

```
import tkinter as tk
import Calendar as cal

class Application(tk.Frame):    
def __init__(self, master = None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.grid()
    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()
def create_widgets(self):
    self.winfo_toplevel().title("Choose date")
    self.sd_button = tk.Label(self, text="Start date")
    self.sd_button.pack()
    self.ed_button = tk.Label(self, text="End date")
    self.ed_button.pack()
    self.sd_date_button = cal.Control(root)
    self.sd_date_button.pack()
    self.ed_date_button = cal.Control(root)
    self.ed_date_button.pack()
root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to implement a button next to "start date" and "end date" that allows me to choose the date like a pop up. 
I found an external code widget from this link that might do the job: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Tkinter-tkinter-calendar-widget

So I capied the code in the link and put in into a "Calendar.py" file.
Unfortunately I have been struggling on how to make it appear effectively in my main code.
Can anyone help me out/give me a hint?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several problems.

You use both pack and grid in `__init__`.

Since you import Calendar.py it's not in your namesapce and you must compensate for that. The name gets to be `Calendar.Calendar` as both the package and class are named Calendar.

Use buttons instead of labels, and associate them with a command to open the calendar.

Save a reference to master so you can call it.

I also bound <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to the printout function.

```
import tkinter as tk
import Calendar

class Application(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.data = {}
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("Choose date")
        self.sd_button = tk.Button(self, text="Start date", command=self.popup)
        self.sd_button.grid()
        self.ed_button = tk.Button(self, text="End date", command=self.popup)
        self.ed_button.grid()
        self.master.bind('<space>', self.print_selected_date)

    def popup(self):
        child = tk.Toplevel()
        cal = Calendar.Calendar(child, self.data)

    def print_selected_date(self, event):
        print(self.data)

root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The class `Control` is not part of the calendar but is included as an example of how to use it. This is a common way of building packages. Look for the line `if __name__ == '__main__':` and there the example will be.

Comment: Thanks so much! There is only one thing I don't have completely clear:
if the "print_selected_date" in the Application class is supposed to print the date that I choose after clicking "ok" in the pop-up. Why doesn't it appear to me in the main widget?

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth here but this is what I believe: Calendar modifies the dict `self.data` instead of returning a value. This works because a dict is mutable. If you want instead to return a value you should study "modal dialogs". They will allow for the program to wait until your dialog is closed and then continue.